# QTcpServer retrieve more than one address

Tags: c++, qt, network-programming, qtcpserver

I use [QTcpServer](http://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-4.7/qtcpserver.html) from the Qt-Framework with C++.

I started it with

```
ret = tcpServer->listen(QHostAddress::Any, 9871)
```

With

```
QHostAddress serverAddress () const
```

I retrieve the Address from it. Which is 0.0.0.0. In my opinion it should listen on more than one address (like 127.0.0.1 and the LAN Address).

Is there a way to retrieve more than one address from this class?

Comment: What do you mean by "retrieve" ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure what your question is exactly, but...

Usually, a `0.0.0.0` means that the socket listen to all interfaces that are both up and configured with a *valid* IPv4 address.

If you want to get all the available IP addresses on the system, you should enumerate the network interface then query their respective IPv4 address (Probably with an `ioctl`, specifying `SIOCGIFSWADDR`).

Comment: Ah ok. Nice to know that this is the meaning of 0.0.0.0. Thanks! that answered my question!

Comment: @Herrbert: You're welcome :) Btw, if you ever need the IPv6 equivalent, it's `::`.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with ereOn's answer above.

If you want to list your network interface adresses, take a look at [QNetworkInterface](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qnetworkinterface.html).